# Which sense of "out" is used here?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of *out* in this case?

> Oh and out on watching the vid. I learned my lesson on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "Out" here most likely means "I'm out" or "Count me out" on the plan to watch a vid.

It's not specified in the context but the speaker had a bad experience previously. ("I learned my lesson on that.")

So this time he isn't going.

Comment: This was a perfect opportunity to make fun of M. Night Shyamalan! Although he's probably got his fill of that fun.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a verbal abbreviation of "over and out", meaning the same thing that Cool Elf said, "Count me out".